# Cannot invoke 'append' with an argument list of type '(String, withName: String)' in Alamofire 4.0

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, alamofire

I'm using Alamofire 4.0 to upload video to server after select or record it through device/camera but when I'm trying to call upload function with append , this error appeared to me in all append statement , what is the wrong in my code.

the second my question about if I want to display progress with percentage of progress during upload how I can make that through Alamofire.

Thanks :)

My code after reading url of selected/recorded video

```
 func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any]) {


    let mediaType:AnyObject? = info[UIImagePickerControllerMediaType] as AnyObject?

    if let type:AnyObject = mediaType {
        if type is String {
            let stringType = type as! String
            if stringType == kUTTypeMovie as String {
                let urlOfVideo = info[UIImagePickerControllerMediaURL] as? NSURL
                if let url = urlOfVideo {
                    // 2

                    print(url)

                    let URL = try! URLRequest(url: "myurl", method: .post, headers: ["Authorization": "auth_token"])


                    Alamofire.upload(multipartFormData: { multipartFormData in

                        multipartFormData.append(url, withName: "videoFile", fileName: "filename", mimeType: "mov")
                        multipartFormData.append("video", withName: "load")
                        multipartFormData.append("record", withName: "type")

                    }, with: URL, encodingCompletion: { (result) in
                        // code
                    })


                }
            } 
        }
    }
    picker.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Regarding the error message:

> Cannot invoke '`append`' with an argument list of type '`(String, withName: String)`'

If we take a look at the `append` methods of `MultipartFormData` of Alamofire:

- [Alamofire/Source/MultipartFormData.swift](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire/blob/master/Source/MultipartFormData.swift)

We note that no `append(...)` method allows a first argument of type `String`, which is what you, however, attempt to use when appending in your `multipartFormData` closure of `Alamofire.upload`.

> ```
> multipartFormData.append("video", withName: "load")
> multipartFormData.append("record", withName: "type")
> ```

I believe you're attempting to use the following method:

> ```
> public func append(_ data: Data, withName name: String) { ... }
> ```

In which case you need to encode your string into the Swift type `Data`, e.g. as follows:

```
multipartFormData.append("video".data(using: .utf8)!, withName: "load")
multipartFormData.append("record".data(using: .utf8)!, withName: "type")
```

---

As for your call:

> ```
> multipartFormData.append(url, withName: "videoFile", fileName: "filename", mimeType: "mov")
> ```

The immutable `url` above is of of type `NSURL`. In Swift 3, you should prefer using Foundation type `URL` instead, which bridge to `NSURL`, but is not the same type. We see in Alamofire 4 that it particularly expects the `URL` type for the `append` function you attempt to call above:

> ```
> public func append(_ fileURL: URL, withName name: String, fileName: String, mimeType: String)
> ```

You've noted yourself that you may use a workaround to call this method by using the `absoluteURL` property of `NSURL` upon your instance `url`; but this simply yields an optional of type `URL`. A better approach would simply be using the `URL` type rather than `NSURL` from the start.

Comment: it's resolved my problem but the first line that is take the URL of video gives this error "Cannot invoke 'append' with an argument list of type '(NSURL, withName: String, fileName: String, mimeType: String)' "

Comment: I solved that by typing .absoluteURL to the URL  multipartFormData.append(url.absoluteURL!, withName: "videoFile", fileName: "filename", mimeType: "mov").

How I can make progress bar during upload video in this case?

Comment: @SamahAhmed `url` is of type `NSURL`. In Swift 3, we may use the Foundation type `URL` rather than `NSURL` (the former bridge to the latter, but is not the same type), and we see in Alamofire 4 that it particularly expects the former type e.g. for `func append(_ fileURL: URL, withName name: String, fileName: String, mimeType: String)`. The `absoluteURL` property of `NSURL` is actually an optional of type `URL`. A better approach would simply be using `URL` rather than `NSURL` from the start.

Comment: @SamahAhmed As for the progress bar: I believe this is out of the scope of the question, it's best to try to limit questions to one specific subject (will increase chance that someone will answer them, as well as allowing the Q&A to be found for prospective future readers). Now that you've solved your syntax errors for the `multipartFormData`, I believe you should create a new question covering specifically how to track the progress, but the step from tracking progress to actually implementing a progress bar is also quite a large one, and I suspect answerers would like to see your own attempt.

Comment: Yes I will do that now :)

Answer (score 0):

We can do this.

```
    static func requestMultiPartFromData(image: UIImage, fileName: String){
        let url = "Your URL HERE"
        Alamofire.upload(
            multipartFormData: { multipartFormData in
                guard let image = image.toString() else { return }
                multipartFormData.append(image.data(using: .utf8)!, withName: fileName)
        },
            to: url,
            encodingCompletion: { encodingResult in
                switch encodingResult {
                case .success(let upload, _, _):
                    upload.responseJSON { response in
                        debugPrint(response)
                    }
                case .failure(let encodingError):
                    print(encodingError)
                }
        }
        )
    }
}
```

With Extension

```
extension UIImage {
    func toString() -> String? {
        let data: Data? = UIImage.pngData(self)()
        return data?.base64EncodedString(options: .endLineWithLineFeed)
    }
}
```