# How to do a multipartFormData upload in Alamofire4?

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, alamofire, alamofireimage

The migration has been nothing short of a nightmare for me. I have this old code from the previous version of Swift/iOS/Alamofire

```
let intVal = 0

Alamofire.upload(.POST, url, headers: ["StringValue": intVal, "StringValue2": "StringValue3"], multipartFormData: { mpfd in
        let image = self.profileImageView.image!
        let imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 0.8)!
        mpfd.appendBodyPart(data: imageData, name: "image", fileName: "custom_image.jpg", mimeType: "image/jpeg")
        }, encodingCompletion: { result in

            switch result {
            case .success(let request, _, _):
                let response = request.response
                print("response from image change: \(response)")
                print("Successfully changed pro pic")
            case .failure/*(let encodingError)*/:
                print("Failed to change pro pic")
            }

    })
```

But now Xcode is giving me an error saying "Ambiguous reference to member 'upload(_:to:method:headers)" but I don't know whether I can trust these error messages because Alamofire fire calls and now throwing thousands of errors, one example is that `encoding: .json` is now `JSONEncoding.default` but Xcode tells me the error is "Extra method in function call". So I tried the solution for most of the other errors which is to switch the method and url arguments

```
Alamofire.upload(url, method: .post, headers ...)
```

But that too doesn't work. How am I supposed to rewrite this to work with the new Swift/Alamofire?

Comment: [Related Q&A](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41401913/cannot-invoke-append-with-an-argument-list-of-type-string-withname-string/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's an example in Alamofire's test suite: https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire/blob/9688b16f0546b97b16c775c75f42b3f4bfacc78e/Tests/UploadTests.swift#L244

```
guard let image = self.profileImageView.image,
  let imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 0.8) else {
    return
}

Alamofire.upload(
  multipartFormData: { multipartFormData in
    mpfd.append(imageData, withName: "image", fileName: "custom_image.jpg", mimeType: "image/jpeg")
  },
  to: url,
  headers: ["Header": value, "Another_Header": value2],
  encodingCompletion: { result in
    // Whatever
  }
)
```

Comment: where would I put a `headers` parameter as in my original? That's actually my main question

Comment: It's an optional parameter on the `upload` function. See https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire/blob/2b65bfe6608a236772b4151b0ec9e82a51a22131/Source/Alamofire.swift#L376 - I edited the answer to include headers